# Правильно ли по смыслу составлено предложение?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, орфография, грамматика

Для организации бесперебойной поставки продуктов питания для экипажей морских судов, в связи с формированием нового Лота на закупку, со сроком действия с июля по декабрь 2021 года.

Comment: В этом предложении явно не хватает глагола.